# How do I display specific entries in mongoDB to react front end with axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

//brief context of application

In my application a user can customise a microreactor (type of object that has many attributes) and then save it which gets saved to mongoDB. The application runs on the MERN stack. After the user creates it, they can view it on a different page.

//the problem

When the user views the microreactors that have been created, ALL microreactors are being shown, microreactors that have been created by other users. I only want microreactors that have been created by the active user to be shown to them.

//how I'm trying to solve it

Here is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MicroreactorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user: {
        type: String
    },

    name: {
        type: Number 
    },

    electrodeOne: {
        type: String
    },

    electrodeTwo: {
        type: String
    },

    temperature: {
        type: String
    },
    
    pressure: {
        type: String
    },

    flowRate: {
        type: String
    },

    reagentOne: {
        type: String
    },

    reagentTwo: {
        type: String

    },

    electrodeArea: {
        type: String
    },

    electrodeDistance: {
        type: String
    },

    vcTemp: [
        String,
    ],
    
    vcTempTime: [
        String
    ],

    vcPressure: [
        String,
    ],

    vcPressureTime: [
        String,
    ],

    vcFlowRate: [
        String,
    ],

    vcFlowRateTime: [
        String
    ],

    tubing: [{
        length: String,
        diameter: String,
        loops: String,
        material: String}]

});

const MicroreactorsModel = mongoose.model("microreactors", MicroreactorSchema);

module.exports = MicroreactorsModel;
```

As you can see the microreactor has the attribute user, this user correlates to the specific user who created the microreactor at the time of creating/saving it.

This is the code that fetches the microreactors and displays it to the user (in the react front end)

```
useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
            setMrViewList(response.data);
            
            
            
        });

        
        
    }, []);
```

This code fetches all microreactors. I want the one that match to the active user. This is the code (below) I tried. I don't think it's possible this way. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
 useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
            
          
           

                for(let i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
   
                    response.data[i].map((mr) => {
                        if(mr.user == localStorage.getItem("userUsername")) {
                            setMrViewList(...mrViewList, response.data[i])

                        }

                    }
                )}
            
            
        });
```

in response to a question
results.data is an object type and is shown as this [image]

As requested the whole code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { AccordionSummary } from '@material-ui/core';
import { LocalConvenienceStoreOutlined, RepeatOneSharp, SettingsBackupRestoreOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';


const View = () => {
    //how parse works
    let w = '["wow", "wowww"]';
    const a = JSON.parse(w);
    // list of micro reactors already created shown in the first row that correlate to session 
    const [mrViewList, setMrViewList] = useState([]);

    // list of all microreactors regardless of username
    const [mrViewListSelected, setMrViewListSelected] = useState([]);

    //state showing time shown in the bottom middle column
    //seconds
    const [timers, setTimers] = useState(0);
    //tens of seconds
    const [timerst, setTimerst] = useState(0);
    //mins
    const [timerm, setTimerm] = useState(0);
    //tens of minutes
    const [timermt, setTimermt] = useState(0);
    //hours
    const [timerh, setTimerh] = useState(0);
    //tens of hours
    const [timerht, setTimerht] = useState(0);
    //turns the timer on and off

    const [timerToggle, setTimerToggle] = useState(false);

    //switches run button to stop upon pressing

    const [buttonStateRun, setButtonStateRun] = useState(true);
    const [buttonStateStop, setButtonStateStop] = useState(false);

    //state that will hide/show the run/stop buttons upon clicking

    const [showStop, setShowStop] = useState(false);

    //state that will show the selected microreactors variable conditions that have been qued
    const [col3vc, setCol3vc] = useState("");

    //states will update the variable conditions qued when a mircroreactor is clicked on

    const [col2Temp, setCol2Temp] = useState("");
    const [col2TempTime, setCol2TempTime] = useState("");
    const [col2Pressure, setCol2Pressure] = useState("");
    const [col2PressureTime, setCol2PressureTime] = useState("");
    const [col2FlowRate, setCol2FlowRate] = useState("");
    const [col2FlowRateTime, setCol2FlowRateTime] = useState("");

    //states will update the variable conditions that have been executed in col 1

    const [col1Temp, setCol1Temp] = useState("");
    const [col1TempTime, setCol1TempTime] = useState("");
    const [col1Pressure, setCol1Pressure] = useState("");
    const [col1PressureTime, setCol1PressureTime] = useState("");
    const [col1FlowRate, setCol1FlowRate] = useState("");
    const [col1FlowRateTime, setCol1FlowRateTime] = useState("");

    //states that will show the times set in h:m:s format
    const [timeT, setTimeT] = useState([]);
    const [timeP, setTimeP] = useState([]);
    const [timeF, setTimeF] = useState([]);

    const [dbTimer, setDbTimer] = useState();
    let dbTimerCounter = 1;

    //state that shows what button has been clicked
    const [microReactorClicked, setMicroReactorClicked] = useState(false);

    //error which will render if run has been clicked without microreactor clicked
    const [microReactorClickedError, setMicroReactorClickedError] = useState();

    const [runButtonClicked, setRunButtonClicked] = useState(false);

    const [runButtonClickedError, setRunButtonClickedError] = useState("");
    

    




    let secs = 0;
    let secsTens = 0;
    let mins = 0;
    let minsTens = 0;
    let hours = 0;
    let hoursTens = 0;

    //instantly increments as set interval will delay by 1s on the first iteration
    const instantIncrements = () => {
        secs ++;
    }

    let tempArray = [];

    const timerid = useRef(0);
    // timer that starts when the run button is clicked
    const startTimer = () => {

        if (microReactorClicked) {
            //sorting out states of what was clicked and not to avoid repeats etc
            setRunButtonClicked(true);
            setMicroReactorClickedError("");
            setDbTimer(0);

            setButtonStateRun(false);
            setButtonStateStop(true);
            //avoids a double delay on first iteration
            instantIncrements();

            tempArray = col2Temp.split(" ");

            timerid.current = setInterval(() => {
                
                if (secs === 10) {
                    secs = 0;
                    //fixes a delay on first increment of secsTens
                    if (secsTens === 0) {
                        setTimerst(1);
                        secsTens = 1;
                    // increments minute by 1 once 60 seconds reached
                    } else if (secsTens === 6) {
                        //fixes a delay on the first incremenet of minute
                        if (mins === 0) {
                            setTimerm(1);
                            mins = 1;
                        //increments tens of minutes after 10 minutes reached
                        } else if (mins === 10) {
                            //fixes a delay in the first increment of minuteTens
                            if (minsTens === 0) {
                                setTimermt(1);
                                minsTens = 1;
                            //increments hour by one once 60 minutes reached
                            } else if (minsTens === 6) {
                                minsTens = 0;
                                setTimermt(0);
                                //fixes delay on first hour
                                if (hours === 0) {
                                    setTimerh(1);
                                    hours = 1;
                                } else if (hours === 10) {
                                    hours = 0;
                                    setTimerh(0);
                                    //fixes delay on first hourTens
                                    if(hoursTens === 0) {
                                        setTimerht(1);
                                        hoursTens = 1;
                                        
                                    }
                                    setTimerht(hoursTens ++);
                                }
                                setTimerh(hours ++);
                            } 
    
                            setTimermt(minsTens ++);
                            
                            mins = 0
    
                            
                        }
                        
                        secsTens = 0;
                        setTimerm(mins ++);
                    }
                    setTimerst(secsTens ++);
                }
                setTimers(secs ++);

                // this part of the counter will listen into the counter wait until the queued conditions time match the timer and will then move them into the executed conditions column
                /*let temporaryCol2Temp = "";

                for (let i=0; i < runTempTime.length; i++) {
                    
                    console.log("iteration " + i + "and value of col2Temp is " + temporaryCol2Temp);
                    if(dbTimerCounter == runTempTime[i]) {        
                        //if col2 has comma find the index of comma
                        console.log("iteration found time to do something");
                        
                        if (col2Temp.includes(',')) {
                            temporaryCol2Temp = col2Temp;                         
                            let indexPoint = temporaryCol2Temp.indexOf(',') + 1;
                            temporaryCol2Temp = temporaryCol2Temp.slice(indexPoint);
                            setCol2Temp(temporaryCol2Temp);
                        } else {
                            setCol1Temp(col2Temp);
                            setCol1TempTime(col2TempTime);
                            setCol2Temp("");
                            setCol2TempTime("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        //console.log(dbTimerCounter + "i is" + i + "runtemp is" + runTemp[i] );
                    }
                }
                */
                
                dbTimerCounter ++;
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            setMicroReactorClickedError("please select a microreactor");
        }
        /* 
        pseudo;
            if microreactor selected run
            else generate error
            check if it has been clicked first
        */
    }

    const startTimerTwo = () => {
        
    }

    const stopTimer = () => {
        setRunButtonClicked(false);
        clearInterval(timerid.current);
        timerid.current = 0;
        setButtonStateRun(true);
        setButtonStateStop(false);
        secs = 0;
        secsTens = 0;
        mins = 0;
        minsTens = 0;
        hours = 0;
        hoursTens = 0;
        setTimers(0);
        setTimerst(0);
        setTimerm(0);
        setTimermt(0);
        setTimerh(0);
        setTimerht(0);
        setCol1Temp("");
        setCol1TempTime("");
        setCol1Pressure("");
        setCol1PressureTime("");
        setCol1FlowRate("");
        setCol1FlowRateTime("");
    }

    
    //states that will be used when the run button is clicked to check if time condition has been satisfied to then move from col3 to col1 
    const [runTemp, setRunTemp] = useState([]);
    const [runTempTime, setRunTempTime] = useState([]);
    const [runPressure, setRunPressure] = useState([]);
    const [runPressureTime, setRunPressureTime] = useState([]);
    const [runFlowRate, setRunFlowRate] = useState([]);
    const [runFlowRateTime, setRunFlowRateTime] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
            
            setMrViewList(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    /*
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        const microreactors = data.find((mr) => mr?.user === localStorage.getItem("userUsername"));
        setMrViewList(microreactors);
        });
    }, []);
    */

    //this state will be responsible for showing the user only microreactors they have created
    //the state is set to an axios get request of the microreactor user attribute

    const deleteMicroreactor = (id) => {
        Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete/${id}`);
        setMrViewList(mrViewList.filter((val) => {
            return val.id != id;
        }))
    }
    
    const [test1, setTest1] = useState("00:33:22s");
    const[test2, setTest2] = useState("");
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='viewContainer'>
                <div className='viewCol1'>
                    <div>Saved Microreactors:</div>
                    {/* 
                    
                    dsfjsdfs
                    sdsd
                    fsd
                    fsdfds
                    fsdfsd
                    fsdf
                    setDetailsFsd
                    fs
                    detailsFsdf
                    sdf
                    sd
                    fs
                    df
                    sdfsdf
                    sd
                    fs
                    df
                    sd
                    fsdfsdfds
                    f
                    sdfsd
                    fsd
                    fs
                    df
                    sd
                    fsdf
                    sdffs
                    df
                    sd
                    fs
                    df
                    sdfs
                    dfsdf
                    sd
                    fs
                    fs
                    */}
                    
                    <button onClick={() => {console.log(tempArray)} }>Check data</button>
                    <div className='view3Buttons'>
                        {mrViewList.map((mr) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={mr.name} onClick={() => {
                                    if (runButtonClicked === false) {
                                        setMicroReactorClicked(true);
                                        setMicroReactorClickedError("");
                                        
                                        //converting string into list
                                        let listVcTemp = JSON.parse(mr.vcTemp);
                                        let listVcTempTime = JSON.parse(mr.vcTempTime);
                                        let listVcPressure = JSON.parse(mr.vcPressure);
                                        let listVcPressureTime = JSON.parse(mr.vcPressureTime);
                                        let listVcFlowRate = JSON.parse(mr.vcFlowRate);
                                        let listVcFlowRateTime = JSON.parse(mr.vcFlowRateTime);

                                        setRunTemp(listVcTemp);
                                        setRunTempTime(listVcTempTime);
                                        setRunPressure(listVcPressure);
                                        setRunPressureTime(listVcPressureTime);
                                        setRunFlowRate(listVcFlowRate);
                                        setRunFlowRateTime(listVcFlowRateTime);
                                        
                                        //e.g col2TempString is a string that will have all the list elements inserted into it from vcTemp in the database to be displayed in col2
                                        let col2TempString = "";
                                        let col2TempTimeString = "";
                                        let col2PressureString = "";
                                        let col2PressureTimeString = "";
                                        let col2FlowRateString = "";
                                        let col2FlowRateTimeString = "";
                                        //e.g concats the data together from the vcTemp
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcTemp.length; i++) {
                                            col2TempString = col2TempString.concat(listVcTemp[i] + ", ");
                                        }
                                        //gets rid of the final ", " in the string and then sets the state to the string
                                        col2TempString = col2TempString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2Temp(col2TempString);
    
                                        let finalListT = [];
                                        //same but for temp time
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcTempTime.length; i++) {
                                            //converting to int
                                            let temporaryIterationT = parseInt(listVcTempTime[i]);
                                            //finding a floored values to get number of hours
                                            let hoursT = Math.floor(temporaryIterationT / 3600);
                                            //same for mins and seconds respectively
                                            let minsT = Math.floor((temporaryIterationT - (hoursT * 3600))/60);
                                            let secsT = Math.floor(temporaryIterationT - (hoursT * 3600) - (minsT * 60));
                                            //setting states to update the new time format as a formatted string
                                            let finalString = `${hoursT}h:${minsT}m:${secsT}s`;
                                                finalListT.push(finalString)
    
                                            col2TempTimeString = col2TempTimeString.concat(finalListT[i] + ", ");
                                        }
                           
                                        col2TempTimeString = col2TempTimeString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2TempTime(col2TempTimeString);
    
                                        //same but for pressure
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcPressure.length; i++) {
                                            col2PressureString = col2PressureString.concat(listVcPressure[i] + ", ");
                                        }
                                     
                                        col2PressureString = col2PressureString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2Pressure(col2PressureString);
                                        
                                        let finalListP = [];
                                        //same but for pressure time
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcPressureTime.length; i++) {
                                            //converting to int
                                            let temporaryIterationP = parseInt(listVcPressureTime[i]);
                                            //finding a floored values to get number of hours
                                            let hoursP = Math.floor(temporaryIterationP / 3600);
                                            //same for mins and seconds respectively
                                            let minsP = Math.floor((temporaryIterationP - (hoursP * 3600))/60);
                                            let secsP = Math.floor(temporaryIterationP - (hoursP * 3600) - (minsP * 60));
                                            //setting states to update the new time format as a formatted string
                                            let finalString = `${hoursP}h:${minsP}m:${secsP}s`;
                                                finalListP.push(finalString)
                                            col2PressureTimeString = col2PressureTimeString.concat(finalListP[i] + ", ");
                                        }
                
                                        col2PressureTimeString = col2PressureTimeString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2PressureTime(col2PressureTimeString);
    
                                        //same but for flowRate
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcFlowRate.length; i++) {
                                            col2FlowRateString = col2FlowRateString.concat(listVcFlowRate[i] + ", ");
                                        }
                                        col2FlowRateString = col2FlowRateString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2FlowRate(col2FlowRateString);
    
                                        let finalListF =[];
                                        //same but for flowRate Time
                                        for(let i=0; i<listVcFlowRateTime.length; i++) {
                                            //converting to int
                                            let temporaryIterationF = parseInt(listVcFlowRateTime[i]);
                                            //finding a floored values to get number of hours
                                            let hoursF = Math.floor(temporaryIterationF / 3600);
                                            //same for mins and seconds respectively
                                            let minsF = Math.floor((temporaryIterationF - (hoursF * 3600))/60);
                                            let secsF = Math.floor(temporaryIterationF - (hoursF * 3600) - (minsF * 60));
                                            //setting states to update the new time format as a formatted string
                                            let finalString = `${hoursF}h:${minsF}m:${secsF}s`;
                                                finalListF.push(finalString)
                                            col2FlowRateTimeString = col2FlowRateTimeString.concat(finalListF[i] + ", ");
                                        }
    
                                        col2FlowRateTimeString = col2FlowRateTimeString.slice(0, -2);
                                        setCol2FlowRateTime(col2FlowRateTimeString);
                                    }

                                    }
                                    
                                }>
                                    <div>Microreactor number: {mr.name}</div>
                                    <button>View</button>
                                    <button>Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='viewCol2'>
                    <div className="viewContainer2">
                        <div className='view2Col1'>
                            <div>
                                Variable condition changes executed:
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Temperature: {col1Temp}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col1TempTime}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Pressure: {col1Pressure}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col1PressureTime}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                FlowRate: {col1FlowRate}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col1FlowRateTime}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className='view2Col2'>
                            Time elapsed: {timerht}{timerh}h:{timermt}{timerm}m:{timerst}{timers}s
                            {buttonStateRun && <button onClick={startTimer}>Run</button>}
                                    {buttonStateStop && <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop</button>}
                            
                            {microReactorClickedError}
                            {runButtonClickedError}

                        </div>
                        <div className='view2Col3'>
                            <div>
                                Variable Conditions qued:
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Temperature: {col2Temp}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col2TempTime}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Pressure: {col2Pressure}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col2PressureTime}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                FlowRate: {col2FlowRate}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Time: {col2FlowRateTime}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default View
```

Response to question: first data type map doesn't work, second data type of object map works

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting `setMrViewList(response.data)` (all the data), and then looping through and trying to find a given entry `response.data[i]` appended to the previous list (`...mrViewList`)? Wouldn't `response.data[i]` already be a part of `response.data`? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: there are two entries in the database, each with different user attributes. setMrViewList was just to make sure that the data was being recorded, I forgot to remove it, I've edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a for-loop, what about `.filter()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
    const { data } = response;
    const microreactors = data.filter((mr) => mr?.user === localStorage.getItem("userUsername"));
    setMrViewList(microreactors);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! with this code I'm getting the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.find is not a function
    at View.js:274:1, a find function would be really helpful but it seems that it doesn't exist?

Comment: @SebR `.find()` is an array function. I assumed your response.data is an array of objects. Also note that I want to perform `.find()` on the `response.data`, not the `response`. If that's still not working, please provide a sample response I can use to test.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I was playing around with the code and sent the wrong error. With the code you put I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: mrViewList.map is not a function. When I type console.log(typeof response.data) The result is object. When I console.log(response.data) I will show the result at the bottom of the original question and edit it now

Comment: @SebR `Uncaught TypeError: mrViewList.map is not a function` -- I am not using `.map()` here, your error is somewhere else. Please post the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: I will add it now to the bottom of the question

Comment: @SebR I am guessing your error is this line: `{mrViewList.map((mr) => { ...`. At some point if `mrViewList` is null, `.map()` throws an exception. Try either `{mrViewList?.map((mr) => { ...` or a ternary operator where you first check e.g. `mrViewList && mrViewList.length > 0 ? {mrViewList.map((mr) => { ... })  : null }`

Comment: I've done that, and I'm console logging what is happening and I can see that your solution is working. I am only getting the result I want in the console log. After adding your additions to the code with the ternary operator the page is now working but it's not displaying any microreactors at all.

Comment: on the console log the type of object thats being saved to the setMrViewList state is an object, and map doesn't work on objects? It's weird because it works if I don't filter the results and change the state to response.data but that too is an object data type

Comment: I added the console log below. The first object is when it is filtered and breaks the map part of the program. The second object is when I get all microreactors but it doesn;t break the map part

Comment: I've solved it!! In the end I just iterated through the list of objects in response.data, and appended the ones that matched the active user to a list, and then set the state to that list which would be displayed to the user. You helped so much with this, thank you so much !

Comment: @SebR Change the "find" in my answer to "filter" and it should work-- find() returns one object, filter returns an array of matching records, since you are expecting multiple. Your code is the same as mine, just not as concise. :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Response.data is generating a list of objects. Iterate through the objects to see if any objects match the username of the active user. If they do then push them to an array.
After the iteration is complete set the state to the array

like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMicroreactors").then((response) => {
           
            let arrayOfMrs = [];
           
            for(let i=0; i < response.data.length;i++) {
                if (response.data[i].user == localStorage.getItem("userUsername")) {
                    arrayOfMrs.push(response.data[i])
                }
            }

            
            
            
            setMrViewList(arrayOfMrs);
            
            
            
        });
        
        
    }, []);
```